# How to take screenshot of active iframe in nested iframes using selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am working on a application with nested iframes and I want to validate content of active iframe.

How to take screenshot of that active iframe?

Comment: can you be little more explanatory regarding iframes HTML ,and what you want to validate .

Comment: You take a screenshot of it like you would any other HTML element. Have you tried that? Post the code you have tried and the result, including any error messages. You also need to add a tag for the language that you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Java is your programming language for the test,
first use switchTo() method to focus on wanted iframe:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("frameId")))
```

Now regarding snapshot of the iframe, I would use [ashot open source library](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/ashot) which could help you take a snapshot of particular element. In your case, it would be the element which located in the highest level inside the iframe.